# how to add elements to a list without the VyRef problem

Tags: c#

I am creating a list of objects but every time I add a new element to the list, it modifies the previous elements.

```
private List<DocRequisicionTransferModel> sendReqMultiple(DocRequisicionTransferModel docRequisicionTransferModel)
        {
            List<DocRequisicionTransferModel> data = new  List<DocRequisicionTransferModel>();
            //doctoReqTransfer.MovimientoRequisicionTransferencia = docRequisicionTransferModel.MovimientoRequisicionTransferencia;
            List<MovRequisicionTransferModel> movRequisicionTransferModels = new List<MovRequisicionTransferModel>();
            movRequisicionTransferModels = docRequisicionTransferModel.MovimientoRequisicionTransferencia;
            List<String> distinctBodegas = docRequisicionTransferModel.MovimientoRequisicionTransferencia.Select(movto => movto.IdBodegaSal).Distinct().ToList();
    

            foreach (String bodega in distinctBodegas)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodega))
                {
                    DocRequisicionTransferModel doctoReqTransfer = new DocRequisicionTransferModel();
                    doctoReqTransfer = docRequisicionTransferModel;
                    doctoReqTransfer.IdBodegaSal = bodega;
                    doctoReqTransfer.MovimientoRequisicionTransferencia = movRequisicionTransferModels.Where(movto => movto.IdBodegaSal.Equals(bodega)).ToList();
                    data.Add(doctoReqTransfer);

                }
                
            } 

            return data;
```

I expect each iteration of the list to store new values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hidden problem behind your code. Just you made the logical error:

```
DocRequisicionTransferModel doctoReqTransfer = new DocRequisicionTransferModel(); // new object is created, but the value of doctoReqTransfer overwrites further  
doctoReqTransfer = docRequisicionTransferModel; // here you assign the same value in each iteration
```

If you need to create the new doctoReqTransfer copying it from docRequisicionTransferModel, add the copying constructor to the DocRequisicionTransferModel class.